# EF Core - Add One to many records

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

Having Models `Cinema` and `Hall` with cardinality 1 <-> 0..n

*Cinema.cs*

```
public class Cinema
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int CinemaId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("city")]
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("halls")]
    [Required]
    public List<Hall> Halls { get; set; } = new List<Hall();
}
```

*Hall.cs*

```
public class Hall
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int HallId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Capacity { get; set; }
    public Cinema Cinema { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public List<Seat> Seats { get; set; } = new List<Seat>();
    public List<MovieShow> Shows { get; set; } = new List<MovieShow>();
}
```

*CinemaRepository.cs*

```
public async Task<Hall> AddHall(int cinemaId, Hall hall) {
  var cinema = await _context.Cinemas.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CinemaId == cinemaId);
  if (cinema == null) { return null; }
  var hallFound = cinema.Halls.FirstOrDefault(cinema => cinema.HallId == hall.HallId);
  if (hallFound != null) { return null; }
  hall.Cinema = cinema;
  await _context.Halls.AddAsync(hall);
  cinema.Halls.Add(hall);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return hall;
}
```

But this only adds `hall` to the `Halls`, with its Cinema property being null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add foreign key to your `Hall` class and modify your `Hall` as follows:

```
    public class Hall
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int HallId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Capacity { get; set; }
    public int CinemaId { get;set;}
    public Cinema Cinema { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public List<Seat> Seats { get; set; } = new List<Seat>();
    public List<MovieShow> Shows { get; set; } = new List<MovieShow>();
}
```

Then in your `CinemaRepository`:

```
 public async Task<Hall> AddHall(int cinemaId, Hall hall)
        {
            var cinema = _context.Cinemas.Include(c => c.Halls).FirstOrDefault(c => c.CinemaId == cinemaId);
            if (cinema == null) { return null; }
            var hallFound = cinema.Halls.FirstOrDefault(cinema => cinema.HallId == hall.HallId);
            if (hallFound != null) { return null; }
            cinema.Halls.Add(hall);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return hall;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am currently trying to figure out why EF Core doesn't want to Update-Database by saying "SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'."

Comment: Because the cinema you query should contain Halls, otherwise the database will not be updated, so you should use Include to query.

Comment: I just added to all tables also int <Model>Id as a foreign key and then ran Add-Migration & Update-Database and this happened. In the repo I have the exact same code as in your answer

Comment: Just add it to your Hall, as provided to me.

Comment: It's quite long. Well I don't know how it happened, but GET /halls started retuning Error Msg "System.InvalidOperationException: The data is NULL at ordinal 2. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling." that's why I wanted to delete table records and tried to Delete all Records, but it returns the same message.

Comment: You should delete the previous database and re-migrate.

Comment: Because there is no foreign key, the data you created before does not have a one-to-many correspondence, so you should regenerate the database and re-establish the relationship.

Comment: I deleted the original db, added a Cinema which returns 
    {
        "cinemaId": 1,
        "name": "CinemaStar",
        "city": "London",
        "halls": []
    }
and then added Hall via /cinemas/1/hall 
{
    "name": "A",
    "capacity": 120,
    "rows": 10,
    "seats": [],
    "shows": []
}
-> and now get /halls
{
        "hallId": 1,
        "name": "A",
        "capacity": 120,
        "cinemaId": 1,
        "cinema": null,
        "rows": 10,
        "seats": [],
        "shows": []
    }
And when I do get /cinemas then it didnt change at all

Comment: If you want to get cinemas,you should use include:`_context.Halls.Include(h=>h.Cinema).ToList()`

Comment: Of course, now I see it...oh my god..thank you so so much for your help, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: It is recommended that you learn about EFCore,glad to help you :)